# PHP Private Variable Access

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

This is a very silly question, but I don't know what's wrong.  I can't get the value of a private variable through a public method.  I'm using CodeIgniter.

```
class someClass extends MY_Model {
  private $table = 'sometable';
  public function getTable() {
    return $this->table;
  }
  public function updateTable($data) {
    $this->db->update($this->getTable(), $data);
  }
}
```

When I call this method from the controller, I get this message:

```
Fatal error: Access level to someClass::$table must be public (as in class MY_Model) in /some/path/someclass.php on line 38
```

What have I done wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parent class `MY_Model` is declaring that field with `public` scope, so you must adhere to that in your child class.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't realize $table is a variable in the super class.